# Looping under a loop on php not working well

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a table on html from MySQL. I'm trying to run while loop under a while loop. But unfortunately my script has a weird behaviour. It's showing following error and not displaying out put correctly.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /home/windsys/public_html/anamika/test2.php on line 27
```

Here is my code. Please tell me what wrong I've done.

```
<?php
require_once('configuration.php');
$con = new mysqli($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}

$q2 = "SELECT DISTINCT type FROM product";
$result2 = $con->query($q2);
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array()) {
    $type = $row2['type'];
    echo "<tr>
              <td class=\"success\"><b>" . $type . "</b></td>
              <td class=\"success\"></td>
              <td class=\"success\"></td>
              <td class=\"success\"></td>
          </tr>";
    //echo $type."</br>";
    $q1 = "SELECT DISTINCT item_name FROM product WHERE type ='$type'";
    $result = $con->query($q1);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $item_name = $row['item_name'];
        $item_name = strtolower($item_name);
        $task = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE item_name='$item_name' AND type='$type'";

        $restask = $con->query($task);
        while ($row3 = $restask->fetch_array()) {
            $item_count++;
            $item_cost += $row3['buying_price'];
            //echo $row['buying_price']."</br>";
        }
        echo "<tr><td></td><td>" . $item_name . "</td><td>" . $item_count
            . "</td><td class=\"text-right\">" . $item_cost . "</td></tr>";

        //echo $row['item_name'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: and your line 27 is?

Comment: while($row3=$restask->fetch_array()){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be your particular issue, assuming you have data in the database, but PHP will throw "Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object" when you attempt to grab a row from a result with 0 rows.

You can prevent this by wrapping your while loop inside of:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    do stuff here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for point the hall of my knowledge. I never thought like that. I'm very much happy to learn the tricks from you. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

> ```
> $task = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE item_name='$item_name' AND type='$type'";
>
> $restask = $con->query($task);
> while ($row3 = $restask->fetch_array()) {
>   ...
> ```

Error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object

The [`mysqli::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) method returns a [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object from a successful `"SELECT"` query, or `FALSE` on error. The error message above means that your query has failed. Check your error logs.

To avoid getting this error, you have to explicitly check for failed queries:

```
$task = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE item_name='$item_name' AND type='$type'";

$restask = $con->query($task);
if ($restask) {
  while ($row3 = $restask->fetch_array()) {
    ...
  }
} else {
  /* Query failed */
}
```